# RPi will not start; No green flashes; Reflashed SD; 5v 1.9A power

Tags: boot, sd-card, power

The title says it all. I bought this Pi from Amazon about 2 weeks ago and, after I shut it down, it refused to boot. I've tried reflashing the SD with wheezy, to no avail. I have a Pi hub. I tried using the power from that, but it still would not start. When I plug in the power, the red light comes on, the act light is VERY dimly lit, and nothing else. My monitor (HDMI->DVI) recognizes that there is a signal, but shows only black. PLEASE HELP ME. I was dancing when I first booted up my Pi. I am a man.

Comment: It does sound like a power issue, otherwise I'm afraid you'll need to return it :( Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Seems your [wall wart 5V 1.9A power supply](http://elinux.org/RPi_5V_PSU_construction) may have died and voltage or current output is low?

Try an alternate source?  Plug into usb port on PC?

If the [RPi on board voltage regulator](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-raspberry-pi-model-b-plus-plus-differences-vs-model-b/power-supply) is faulty (To prove you use multimeter to check 5V rail and 3.3V) you can replace components

You could possibly power it via the IDC header and bypass the  DMG2305UX P-Channel MOSFET which may have partially died?

Comment: I said I used the power from the Pi hub

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an other SD?

because I recently cracked the SD socket of my Pi and therefore I couldn't locate the SD card correctly. It also resulted with that dim green light and so on. Just buy a new SD and try to boot it with the brand new one again.